# PG::ERROR: another command is already in progress

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, import, pg

I have an importer which takes a list of emails and saves them into a postgres database. Here is a snippet of code within a tableless importer class:

```
query_temporary_table = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE subscriber_imports (email CHARACTER VARYING(255)) ON COMMIT DROP;"
query_copy            = "COPY subscriber_imports(email) FROM STDIN WITH CSV;"
query_delete          = "DELETE FROM subscriber_imports WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM subscribers WHERE suppressed_at IS NOT NULL OR list_id = #{list.id}) RETURNING email;"
query_insert          = "INSERT INTO subscribers(email, list_id, created_at, updated_at) SELECT email, #{list.id}, NOW(), NOW() FROM subscriber_imports RETURNING id;"

conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
conn.transaction do
  raw = conn.raw_connection

  raw.exec(query_temporary_table)
  raw.exec(query_copy)
  CSV.read(csv.path, headers: true).each do |row|
    raw.put_copy_data row['email']+"\n" unless row.nil?
  end
  raw.put_copy_end
  while res = raw.get_result do; end # very important to do this after a copy

  result_delete = raw.exec(query_delete)
  result_insert = raw.exec(query_insert)

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
  {
    deleted:  result_delete.count,
    inserted: result_insert.count,
    updated:  0
  }
end
```

The issue I am having is that when I try to upload I get an exception:

```
PG::ERROR: another command is already in progress: ROLLBACK
```

This is all done in one action, the only other queries I am making are user validation and I have a DB mutex preventing overlapping imports. This query worked fine up until my latest push which included updating my pg gem to 0.14.1 from 0.13.2 (along with other "unrelated" code).

The error initially started on our staging server, but I was then able to reproduce it locally and am out of ideas.

If I need to be more clear with my question, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found my own answer, and this might be useful if anyone finds the same issue when importing loads of data using "COPY"

An exception is being thrown within the CSV.read() block, and I do catch it, but I was not ending the process correctly.

```
  begin
    CSV.read(csv.path, headers: true).each do |row|
      raw.put_copy_data row['email']+"\n" unless row.nil?
    end
  ensure
    raw.put_copy_end
    while res = raw.get_result do; end # very important to do this after a copy
  end
```

This block ensures that the COPY command is completed. I also added this at the end to release the connection back into the pool, without disrupting the flow in the case of a successful import:

```
rescue
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

Comment: There's also [a more complete example](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/tip/sample/copyfrom.rb) of how to do this with a raw PG connection in the `pg` library's sample directory. It adds error-handling and shows how you might want to use the Result object you get from #get_result.

Comment: Just to add another note, it isn't necessary to checkin(conn) if you use the existing connection:

conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection